# mongodb aggregate always return null in array of the collection object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a person like this,
The person has many companies, [ ONE TO MANY ]

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eef12533167638883fba5ad"),
        "companies" : [  
                         ObjectId("00000000000000000011111") , 
                         ObjectId("0000000000000000022222") 
                      ],
        "email" : "test@mailinator.com",
        "phoneNumber" : "+1689999999999",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-21T07:54:56.529Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-21T07:54:56.529Z")
}
```

I want to aggregate companies into the company data
I am trying like this

```
db.people.aggregate(
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "companies",
    "localField": "companies",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "companies"
  }},
)
```

but the result is the same as query db.people.find()
how to correct way to query that she in that array show the companies data ,

what I expected is :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eef12533167638883fba5ad"),
        "companies" : [  
                         {
                           "_id": ObjectId("00000000000000000011111"),
                            "name": "Company one"
                          },
                           ..... so on
                      ],
        "email" : "test@mailinator.com",
        "phoneNumber" : "+1689999999999",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-21T07:54:56.529Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-21T07:54:56.529Z")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT:** Starting MongoDB 3.4, if the `localField` is an array, you can match the array elements against a scalar `foreignField` without needing an $unwind stage.

I believe your aggregate call is not right. `.aggregate()` receives an array.

```
db.people.aggregate([
  { 
   $lookup: {
    from: "companies",
    localField: "companies",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "companies"
   }
  }
])
```

Make sure the `from`, `localField` and `foreignField` are correct.

Comment: you are right, and I was wonder why my query always got empty on companies, because  that companies not in the database or deleted LOL, oh ye one more, what is the condition for people company, like say I want to aggregate companies in that people that company created at last month ??

Comment: See this document. It describes how to handle conditions and multiple joins.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup